# Swift: Unique Int id from String

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse which has an preload User table in the database. I want from each user a unique userId (Int). Parse's objectId is unique but not an Int and username is a String. Username is unique for each user , so can I somehow convert each username into a number ?

I tried .toInt() , Int() but I got nothing.

WHY :
I have an existing table with user's ratings (movies) and I want to extent this table with more ratings. The userId field is a Number value so I must keep it this way.

Comment: You cannot convert random strings to integers and keep uniqueness. Can you explain why you need integer identifiers?

Comment: Can you provide some examples. Like `input` => `output`

Comment: You should be using pointers to achieve this

Answer (score 8):

Swift `String` has a `hash` property. It also conforms to the [`Hashable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/index.html). Maybe you can use that.

However, `hashValue` has the following comment:

> Axiom:x == y implies x.hashValue == y.hashValue.
>
> Note: The hash value
>   is not guaranteed to be stable across different invocations of the
>   same program. Do not persist the hash value across program runs.

so, use carefully...

**Note**: as stated in the comments, the `hashValue` is not guaranteed to be unique, but collisions should be rare, so it may be a solution anyway.

Comment: I also agree with the comments on the question:  "why?"

Comment: @MartinR That's correct, but collisions should be rare, maybe it is enough for the intended use.

Comment: @danh Actually, it's the other way arround... Given two different hashes, the strings are guaranteed to be different. But two different strings can generate the same hash value... Again, that should not happen often, so maybe the `hashValue` works.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino: Such a statement would require that we know *how* the hash property is implemented for Swift strings. It may be true, but *I* don't know. (As an example, the hashValue property of NSArray simply returns the number of elements :)

Answer (score 3):

Having unique arbitrary String to Int map is not possible.  You have to put some constraints on the allowed characters and string length.  However, even if you use case-insensitive alpha-numeric user names, with some smart variable-length bit-encoding, then you look at some 5 bits per character on rough average.  64-bit integer can accomodate up to some 12 characters this way.  Longer than that, you will inevitably have collisions.

I think you approach the problem from the wrong end.  Instead of having a function for String -> Int mapping, what stops you from having a separate table with Int <-> String mapping?  Just have some functionality that will check whether a userID exists in that table, and if it does not, then insert a new record for such userID and assign a new unique number to it.  This way it will take quite some time and service popularity to deplete 64-bit integer capacity.

Comment: Was just writing up the same.  int64 range is 2^64, while strings, even just ascii strings, are much more expressive, say 2^(7*length).  to guarantee a unique id, you'll map the smaller space (int) into the bigger space (sting).

Comment: hes generating a user id of fixed size. there is always going to be a possibility of a clash. it doesn't matter. all he has to do is check for a clash before he uses it. doing what you suggest doesn't let him meet his requirements.